# ¿Cómo listar un array en php?

Tags: php

Debo listar un array (un calendario) como una lista, pero cuando uso `echo` no me lista como necesito.

He visto que se puede con la función `list()`.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo como [print_r](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php)?

Comment: Si,pero como leei por ahi imprime en pantalla un array multidimensional  pero no dice nada sobre listar,disculpa mi ignorancia en php,no cuentas con un info sobre esa funcion?

Comment: puedes ser más especifico? mostrar tu código y tu objetivo?

Comment: @Sommer el enlace que hay en print_r es a la página oficial de PHP en español. No termino de comprender el problema, ¿qué es lo que intentas hacer?

Answer (score 0):

si quieres ver los valores que tienes dentro del array usa [var_dump(variable)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), de todas maneras te recomiendo que uses un loop y pases la información del vector a variables y desde allí si podrás hacer echo's con html :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes diferentes formas de imprimir un arreglo y dependerá también si es que la impresión es simplemente para depurar código o para mostrarla al usuario final. En caso sea únicamente para depurar, puedes hacer uso de:

```
print_r
var_dump
```

Te recomiendo más utilizar print_r pues **var_dump** si es que los contenidos del arreglo son muy grandes, no los mostrará de manera completa.

Adicionalmente, si quieres darle un buen formato a la impresión del arreglo en modo de depuración, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Lo cual mostrará tu arreglo de manera ordenada. En caso quieras imprimir un arreglo para mostarlo al usuario final, puedes recorrer elemento por elemento e imprimirlo con el formato que desees mediante un for, foreach (u otros métodos que existen). Te dejo un par de links que hablan sobre lo más básico de arreglos que posiblemente te sea útil.

http://blog.aulaformativa.com/conceptos-basicos-sobre-los-arrays-php/
http://blog.aulaformativa.com/recorriendo-un-array-en-php-con-foreach/

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo básico de recorrer un array

```
$CALENDARIO = Array(1=>"Cumpleaños",2=>"Cena con amigos");

foreach($CALENDARIO as $dia=>$descripcion){
 echo "El día" . $dia . " tengo que ir a " . $descripcion;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

como te comentan por ahí una de las opciones es `print_r($array);`
Y si utilizas:

```
print_r("<pre>");
print_r($array);
print_r("</pre>");
```

Verás el array formateado, con lo que lo verás más claro

Answer (score 0):

Las dos funciones que tienes son:

**var_dump** muestra la estructura incluyendo el tipo y valor. Los Arrays son explorados recursivamente con los valores indentados para mostrar la estructura.

**print_r** muestra la estructura de un modo mas leíble para humanos. Los valores del Array son presentados en un formato que muestra las claves y elementos, la notación es similar para objetos.

Ejemplo:

```
$obj = (object) array('Italia', 'Francia', 'Alemania');
var_dump($obj)
```

Salida:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
 [0]=> string(12) "Italia"
 [1]=> string(12) "Francia"
 [2]=> string(5) "Alemania"
}
```

Y, print_r($obj)

```
stdClass Object ( 
 [0] => Italia
 [1] => Francia
 [2] => Alemania
)
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta con lo siguiente:

```
foreach($list as $element) {    
    echo "< br>";
    echo $element;
    echo "< br>";
}
```